# I wrote code to convert decimal fraction number to its binary equivalent. It compiles fine but when executed hangs

Tags: c++

I wrote code to convert decimal fraction number to its binary equivalent. It compiles fine but when executed hangs. The code here prints only first four digits of the binary conversion and if the number if with more than 4 digits, it shows '...' after it. On execution it hangs. Help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, x[10];
    float num;
    cout << "**PROGRAM TO CONVERT DECIMAL FRACTION INTO ITS EQUIVALENT BINARY**\n";
    cout << "Enter a fraction in between 0 to 1 for conversion: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (num>=0 && num<=1)
    {
        i=1;
        while (num!=1.000)
        {
            num*=2;
            x[i]=num;
            num=num-x[i];
            i++;
        }
            if (i>4)
            {
                cout << "The binary equivalent is 0.";
                for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
                {
                    cout << x[i];
                }
                cout << "...";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The binary equivalent is 0.";
                for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
                {
                    cout << x[i];
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The number entered is out of range.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *It compiles fine but when executed hangs.* -- A program compiling fine only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether your program has logical errors  or not.  Second, forget about using `float`.  This problem is solved using string and integer division by 2.  Usage of `float` automatically makes your program subject to `float` not being exact.  For example, if the input is `0.1` and the type is `float`, you've already introduced round-off issues.

Comment: Input a `string`, extract each digit from left to right, and do repeated division by 2.  In other words, convert decimal to binary using the same "by hand" division technique you learned in an elementary computer science class.

Answer (score 1):

The first obstacle is the infinite while loop:

Assuming input num=0.5

- after first iteration, i=1, x[0]=1, num=0.0
- after second iteration, i=2, x[1]=0, num=0.0
- Continue forever, i=..., x[i-]1=0, num=0.0

With nothing to break the loop.

```
 while (num!=1.000)
        {
            num*=2;
            x[i]=num;
            num=num-x[i];
            i++;
        }
```

To fix, consider few changes. There might be other issues.

1. put a limit on the while loop (i<10 should be a good condition, as this is the size of the `x` array), or i=4, as this is the maximum output.
2. The break condition for the while loop should probably be 'num != 0', or even better (num > 1e-7, or other small value).

Comment: But how will it be able to print '...' if the binary conversion has more than 4 digits. BTW thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

float has 23 bit in mantissa, maybe it is because you are assign x[i] with i greater than 9.

try this:

```
    //stop when you get four bits
    while (i< 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Original code has several issues:

1 For input num=.5 and similar (really for all values) cycle never ends ([dash-o](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136579/7163942) suggested fix ideas)

2 array  x[10] is overflowed with undefined behavior ([Edney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136578/7163942))

3 nitpicking: 1 is not a “fraction” and better check for a range 0 <= num < 1 instead of 0 <= num <= 1(see also OP printing code; 1 could be added); we could use x[4] with 0<=i <=3

4 string could also be used ([PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136448/i-wrote-code-to-convert-decimal-fraction-number-to-its-binary-equivalent-it-com/60143507#comment106362722_60136448)). Really “>>” uses string processing for parsing and calculating binary equivalent from which by multiplying by 2 (left shit) and truncation fractional part the code calculates target bits. Both approaches give correct identical results; implementing by string we need to add internal to operator “>>” implementation code to parsing valid formats for floats (decimals) such as 3.14e-1, .2718, 1e-1, etc.

This fix follows OP:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, x[5];
    float num;
    cout << "**PROGRAM TO CONVERT DECIMAL FRACTION INTO ITS EQUIVALENT BINARY**\n";
    cout << "Enter a fraction in between 0 to 1 for conversion: ";
    cin >> num;
    if (num>=0 && num<1)
    {
        i=1;
        while (i<=4)
        {
            num*=2;
            x[i]=num;
            num=num-x[i];
            i++;
        }

        cout << "The binary equivalent is 0.";
        for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            cout << x[i];
        }
        if (num>0)
                cout << "...";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The number entered is out of range.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is without cycles (they are in code implementing “>>”, bitset):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  const int digits = 4;
  int fraction;
  float num;

  cout << "**PROGRAM TO CONVERT DECIMAL FRACTION INTO ITS EQUIVALENT BINARY**\n";
  cout << "Enter a fraction in between 0 to 1 for conversion: ";

  cin >> num;

  if (num >= 0 && num < 1) {
    fraction = num = num * pow (2, digits);

    cout << "The binary equivalent is 0.";

    cout << bitset<digits> (fraction);

    if (num - fraction > 0) cout << "...";
  }
  else cout << "The number entered is out of range.";
}
```